# Yii: how to respond with 404

Tags: web, yii, http-status-code-404

How do I generate a response in *Yii* using *$this->render*, while setting an answer code to 404 instead of 200?

I want my flow to be like this:

```
if ($isOk) {
  $this->render('page', ...);
} else {
  // set 404 header  
  $this->render('error', ...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should throw **Exception** instead:

```
if ($isOk) {
   $this->render('page', ...);
} else {

   throw new CHttpException("404", "Your requested page not found.");
}
```

This will render `error` view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
http_response_code(404);
$this->render(...........);
Yii::app()->end();
```